# MYSQL Mathematical Operations Priority

Tags: php, mysql, mathematical-expressions

this my code:

```
$stmt->prepare("UPDATE ".$PapierTableName."  SET nrating=nrating+1,`rating`=(rating+?)/nrating  WHERE `id`=? AND `title`=?");
$stmt->bind_param('iis', $rat,$id,$tit);
```

My question is about the priority: in this operation

```
`rating`=(rating+?)/nrating
```

the `nrating` that will be used is the one already incremented or the one that is present in column?
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That already incremented one; due to [Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

> Parentheses may be used to force precedence, if necessary

Comment: So if I swap the operation the other one will be used,doesn't it?

Comment: yep, if you reverse it, you will divide by the original value, and then increment it